# What's going on with tags on profile pages on SF?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Owww, my eyes.

(10/12/10, 15:09pm, Windows 7 32-bit, IE 8)

[image: http://static.tombullock.co.uk/images/tags.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The devs are aware - please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71913/tags-on-user-page-are-not-formatting-correctly-on-server-fault